# How do you return a non primitive type variable in golang

Tags: go, interface, dry

How do you return a non primitive type variable in golang

Comment: You want to put some code into a function. Okay. Just do it. Where is the problem? Are you overthinking it? Stop trying to do "generic" stuff with the excuse of "DRY" (or any other nonsense acronym).

Comment: That wasn't the issue. As I stated, all I wanted to know was, " how to return this" This being how do I return a non primitive type from another package library such as bigquery.NewClient(). What do I need to specify as a return type for the function in order to do this. Sorry if you misunderstood.

Comment: There is _no_ _difference_ between "primitive types" and other types. I'd recommend taking the Tour of Go.

Comment: Again, not what I was asking but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `bigquery.NewClient` returns a `(*Client, error)`, so if you're trying to encapsulate that, you can probably just write a function that returns a `*bigquery.Client`

Comment: Oh, so you must include a pointer to the package name and struct that it references. This answers it perfectly. Thanks Adam this is what I was looking for

Comment: @fjson01 no, you must provide the type you're returning. In this case, since you're referring to `bigquery.NewClient` as such, it's clear that `Client` is named `bigquery.Client` in your context. Since `NewClient` returns a pointer to a `Client`, you must return a pointer as well (or resolve that pointer in your wrapping function, but that seems bad.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with Volker that you should take the Tour of Go. You seem to be misunderstanding some fundamental aspects of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want a helper go file instantiated as a singleton in OOPS terms.

```
package somehelper

type SomeData struct {
    SubData1 SubDataType1
    SubData2 SubDataType2
}

var singleton *SomeData
var once sync.Once

func Createsingleton(data1 SubDataType1, data2 SubDataType2) {
    once.Do(func() {
        singleton = &SomeData{SubData1:data1, SubData2: data2}
    })
}

func GetSingleton() *SomeData {
    if singleton == nil {
        panic("SomeDataHelper needs to be instantiated!!!")
    }
    return singleton
}


func (i *SomeData) GetSubData1() SubData1{
    return i.SubData1
}
```